Auth0 Django Backend Api
buenos dias. Estoy usando auth0 Okta aplicandolo en backend api con Django. Tengo un problema es que por mas que le asigne los roles a una persona en especifico esta no tiene acesso. Cuando la persona se logea mediante el fronted que me brinda auth0. Recibo esto en el scope ['openid', 'profile', 'email'] (berear o jwt diferente ).
Cuando yo lo hago via postman, recibo lo siguiente:
"scope": "read:messages", entiendo que no es la forma correcta dado que yo le especifico el permiso del usuario
